# Returning list of customers from user form defined values php/sql form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently I am working on some code that would allow a user to enter in two values (in this case two zip codes) and when submitted, the program would return the values equal to and between the codes. For example, if 123456 and 234567 were entered as beginning and ending zip codes respectively, it would return customers with only zip codes in that range.

I have been able to do this with SQL by hard coding in a pre determined range directly in the SQL command. But I would like to do this with the variables that the user enters. Which I am to believe that would be done in the final fetch command.

```
$SQL = "SELECT LastName, FirstName, Address1, City, State, Zip FROM Customers ORDER BY LastName ASC;";
try {
    $sth = $conn->prepare($SQL);
    $sth->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error selecting customer records: " . $e->getMessage();
    die;
}

echo "Query excecuted successfully. <br />";

if($sth->rowCount()==0) {
    echo "No records returned. <br />";
    die;
} else {
    echo $sth->rowCount() . " records returned. <br /> <br />";
}

while($result = $sth->fetch()){
    //in an array, refer to column with string inside brackets ['rid']
    echo "LastName: " . $result['LastName'] . "<br />";
    echo "FirstName: " . $result['FirstName'] . "<br />";
    echo "Address1: " . $result['Address1'] . "<br />";
    echo "City: " . $result['City'] . "<br />";
    echo "State: " . $result['State'] . "<br />";
    echo "Zip: " . $result['Zip'] . "<br /> <br />";
}
```

In the initial $SQL statement I can use the WHERE Zip BETWEEN ## AND ## to get what I want, but I want to use the user defined variables. How would I go about that? I have looked quite extensively, but I must not be using the proper terms.

Comment: Just a note on error reporting: [You are not the only user of your site.](https://phpdelusions.net/programming#reporting_errors)

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will try my best to shift my practices to something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use placeholders (`?`) and bind user input to them implicitly in `->execute()`:

```
$zipFrom = $_POST['zipFrom'];
$zipTo   = $_POST['zipTo'];
// TODO: validate input data

$SQL = "SELECT LastName, FirstName, Address1, City, State, Zip 
        FROM Customers 
        WHERE Zip BETWEEN ? AND ?
        ORDER BY LastName ASC";
$sth = $conn->prepare($SQL);
$sth->execute([$zipFrom, $zipTo]);
```

You can also use named placeholders to make your query more readable:

```
$SQL = "SELECT LastName, FirstName, Address1, City, State, Zip 
        FROM Customers 
        WHERE Zip BETWEEN :zip_from AND :zip_to
        ORDER BY LastName ASC";
$sth = $conn->prepare($SQL);
$sth->execute([
    'zip_from' => $zipFrom,
    'zip_to'   => $zipTo
]);
```

You can put the code into a try-catch-block. But there's no point doing that, if you just want to dump the error message.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This is kind of what I thought I had to do, but could not come up with the right terms to search it seems. I've used both examples and found that I like the second one, as it is easier to read. But on the last part do you mean by just removing the error message entirely? It is kind of extraneous, but it was more or less there to help me figure out my errors as they happened since these are easier to me than some of the generic error messages if that makes any sense. Still learning though and am open to suggestions! Thank-you again though!

Comment: @Sparky "do you mean by just removing the error message entirely?" - Yes. The "generic error messages" will not only contain the filename and line number, but also a stacktrace (function call trace) so you can easily find where to fix your code. The "broken" code is not always where the error has been triggered. IMHO the best way to handle errors/exceptions is to write a global handler. Take a look at [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)